# Finding the Big oh notation for my algorithm which uses arraylist.contains

Tags: java, arraylist

I am in the process of learning about big oh notation. For the code below, I have a program that counts the number of words, skipping over the delimiters. For this algorithm, the for loop would be for the length of the sentence and then there is contains that iterates to the string as well. So according to me the the big oh notation for this algorithm would be O(n^3). Is that correct or am I missing something about big Oh notation ?

```
public class wordCount {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String sentence = "How are you,zak;far: mon. day ?:";
    int count = 1;
    ArrayList<Character> delim = new ArrayList<Character>();
    delim.add(' ');
    delim.add(',');
    delim.add('.');
    delim.add(':');
    delim.add(';');
    delim.add('"');
    delim.add('\'');
    for (int i = 0; i != sentence.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (delim.contains(sentence.charAt(i))) {
            if (!delim.contains(sentence.charAt(i + 1))) {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The count is: " + count);
}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you're not quite right - you're assuming that the "n" of the O(n) of `contains` is the same as the "n" that you're interested in. It's not - it's the length of the array list. In this case, that's the number of delimiters, not the sentence length.

So your algorithm is actually O(N * M) where N is the sentence length and M is the number of delimiters. If you view the set of delimiters as constant with only your sentence as input, your whole algorithm is O(N).

Even though you call `contains` conditionally the second time, the total number of `contains` calls per iteration is only ever 1 or 2 - it can't grow to (say) the number of delimiters or the size of the sentence.

Comment: @Tudor: Yes, had just noticed that. For some reason I thought we were looping for the inner contains. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

It's not that simple. Assume we call the length of the string N and the length of `delim` M.

For each char in the string you are calling `delim.contains(...)` once or twice (which is O(M)), so the final complexity should be O(N x M).

Answer (score 1):

Since this feels very much like homework (and if it is please add the `homework` tag), I'll provide some observations rather than a solution:

You have two different "N"'s here, the length of `sentence` and the number of items in `delim`.  Those numbers can be vastly different.

You need to understand the big Oh performance of `ArrayList<T>.Contains`.  Do you know what that is?

Answer (score 0):

You have to think about how many loops are inside loops (and how far those loops go)

You have no more than two loops inside each other, not three.

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence.length()-1; i++) { // loop level 1
    boolean isDelim = delim.contains(sentence.charAt(i));  // loop level 2
    if (!isDelim) continue;

    if (!delim.contains(sentence.charAt(i + 1)))  // loop level 2
        count++;
}
```